# Does a mongod Configserver also contain data (except metadata)?

Tags: mongodb, architecture, nosql

I am getting started with MongoDB and cannot find the answer to the question.
For test purposes I want to create a 3 Datanode Cluster, but so far I am not sure how many machines i will need to start a cluster with 3 Datanodes. I want to have 2 routingservers in the cluster.

My current understanding is that I will need 4 machines.

1. Machine (Configserver and Routingserver): runs `mongod --configsrv` and `mongos`
2. Machine (Shard and Routingserver): runs `mongod` and `mongos`
3. Machine (Shard): runs only the `mongod`
4. Machine (Shard): runs only the `mongod`

So in my opinion a `mongod --configsrv` cannot be a shard at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB the config server will store any data other than metadata for a sharded cluster. If you manually connect to the config server and try to write data, you get this error:

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 14037,
            "errmsg" : "can't create user databases on a --configsvr instance"
    }
})
```

Regarding the number of servers, each shard should run on its own machine. As you only have two shards, you can get away with 2 machines, however, 4 would be desirable so you can have a primary and a secondary replica set for both shards. The config server and routing servers can be run on any of the four machines, so you only need 4 machines.